# Use Yelp API to search for restaurants by category using Python script

Tags: python, yelp

I would like to search Yelp API for restaurants by category. However, the keyword I use gets me an invalid error. Here's what I mean:

Using Python code (search.py) from: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python

I have the following query:

```
python search.py --consumer_key=XXX --consumer_secret=XXXX \
--token=XXX --token_secret=XXX --location="sf" --term="restaurants" --category='Indian'
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "field": "category_filter", 
    "id": "INVALID_PARAMETER", 
    "text": "One or more parameters are invalid in request"
  }
}
```

Could you show me the correct query for category to make this work? Please note that when I remove the --category keyword, the query works.

Comment: how about "Indian" with double quotes ?

Comment: does not change anything. Get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the category identifier "indpak"

see:
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/category_list
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api#searchGP

Comment: changing it to "indpak" gets me the same error. :-(

Comment: I am able to run the query using search.py.  Only difference I spot is that I do not use quotes, but I tested with both single and double quotes on the category and it works fine.

Comment: Well,could you get me the string you use. Because clearly I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Or please send me the URL that is generated.

Comment: `python search.py --consumer_key=XXXX --consumer_secret=XXXX --token=XXXX --token_secret=XXXX --location=sf --term=restaurants --category=indpak`

Comment: Very strange. I have idea what I was doing wrong but it works now. Thanks a bunch!!